# JS concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following chunk of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var image_url = 'wp-content/themes/lacitta/images/section_1.jpg';
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
        image_url = 'wp-content/themes/lacitta/images/section_2.jpg';
    }
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + image_url + ')');
});
</script>
```

I want to add a "50% 50% no-repeat" after the image like this: `background:url(images/background.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;`. However, everytime I try to add it the script stops working. Being a total beginner in JS I'll post here what I tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var extra = ' 50% 50% no-repeat';
    var image_url = 'wp-content/themes/lacitta/images/section_1.jpg';
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
        image_url = 'wp-content/themes/lacitta/images/section_2.jpg';
    }
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + image_url + ')' + extra + '');
});
</script>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Is it a concatenation problem?

The point of the script is to change the background image when scrolling and it's working without the "50% 50% no-repeat;" part.

Comment: background-image only supports the url() component. if you want to set positioning/sizing, it'd have be just `background : url(...) 50% 50% no-repeat`. and if it was a concatentation issue, then it'd be a JS syntax error, and you'd be told so in your browser's debug console.

Comment: Yes, that's what I intend to achieve. the "extra" variable is placed wrong?

Comment: no, it's positioned correctly. ignoring the css issue itself, there's nothing wrong with the JS as-written.

Comment: Ah, I got it now, thanks! :) please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background-image` doesn't accept sizing/position arguments. it's `url()`-only, basically. Your code should be

```
$('body').css('background', 'url(' + image_url + ')' + extra);
                         ^---no "-image"                    ^-- + '' isn't necessary
```